# How should I handle a question whose answer I can no longer verify?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858143/winscp-how-to-make-sure-sftp-upload-gets-renamed-from-zip-filepart-to-zip/29504635#29504635) a few years ago, and someone added an answer yesterday.

I'm no longer working on this project and do not have access to the FTP server that was the source of the issue, so I'm not in a position to be able to check the recommended solution.

Should I close the question?

EDIT: While my question is similar to the proposed duplicate, it's slightly different because it involves an inability to test the solutions offered, rather than simply having moved on to other work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You couldn't close the question even if you wanted to.  You don't have unilateral close rights over the question.

If you feel you aren't in a position to give feedback as to the quality of the answer, then don't vote on it, or accept it as the answer.  If other members of the community feel that they are qualified to judge the quality of the answer, they can vote on it.

SE was built on the premise that while the person that asked the question can provide feedback on the answers give, they're not the *only* one who can judge which answers were helpful and not helpful.  All* community members can provide feedback, allowing readers to know which posts are most helpful even if the post author can't judge them (or even if they judge them incorrectly).

*Well, all community members with 15 rep for upvotes, or 125 rep for downvotes anyway.

Comment: Quick, OP, verify this answer while you can. (Or, at least, once you can in a few minutes.)